# IIS suddenly responds extremely slow

Tags: iis, iis-7

Without touching the server at all, my IIS 7 suddenly got terribly slow. No matter if I request a static content, a php script via FastCGI or a ASP.NET page, it sometimes takes more than 30 seconds for the server to send the response (even for a 1k static file).
The resources are not utilized at all (~1% CPU, enough main memory free). The failed request trace from IIS shows for all those slow responses for every step 0ms processing time, but a total processing time of a few thousand milliseconds. It's also not a networking issue (Apache on the same server runs smooth and the same latency applies for local requests).
Anyone has an idea what else to test/check? Have you seen such behavior as well?

Comment: You're saying using Apache locally provides the same latency? What is your benchmark for remote calls to both web server instances?

Comment: Is your hard drive dying?

Comment: Using Apache remotely provides the same latency (Apache running on the exact same server). The hard drive is just fine, as Apache has no problems reading from it.

Comment: Sorry, I meant much better latency and not the same.. So whatever webserver I test with, the results are way better than with IIS. Therefore it's definitely not a networking issue.